# how to keep sortable elements in one line during dragging

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to make children sortable inside parent on x-axis. It works but during moving an element rest of them changes their paddings or margins, i.e. they go bellow the active element.

```
<div id='parent'>
<div class='tagup'>EARTH</div>
<div class='tagup'>SUN</div>
<div class='tagup'>MOON</div>
<div class='tagup'>VENUS</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent{
  padding:5px 10px;  
  background:lightgreen;
}
.tagup{
  display:inline-block;
  background:darkblue;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:1px 5px;
  margin:3px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#parent').sortable({
axis: "x",
containment: 'parent',
tolerance: "pointer",
});
```

Here is an [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bonaca/sd1zvuvz/)

How to keep them in one line during dragging?
g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sortable sets contaner's height. Let's set height auto of tagup.

```
.tagup{
  display:inline-block;
  height:auto !important; //Add this line
  background:darkblue;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:1px 5px;
  margin:3px;
}
```